# scala how to concatenate two list of class

Tags: list, scala, concatenation

I have this class

```
 case class User(var userId: Int, var userName: String, var email:      
String, var password: String) {
  def this() = this(0, "", "", "")
}
```

I have two list same User type list
 teamMembers 
 usrList

I want to concatenate both into one teamMembers. I don't know how to do it so tried as:

```
 teamMembers:::usrList 
 teamMembers = teamMembers:::usrList
 teamMembers++usrList
 teamMembers = teamMembers++usrList
```

Nothing seems to be working. I guess it must be easy. Just having difficulties to understand scala doc. How to concatenate them into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the operator `++=` for appending a list to a (mutable) list; for instance for

```
case class User(var userId: Int = 0, 
                var userName: String = "", 
                var email: String = "", 
                var password: String = "")
```

and

```
var teamMembers = List ( User(0), User(1) )
val usrList = List( User(3) )
```

we have that

```
teamMembers ++= usrList
```

and so

```
teamMembers
List[User] = List(User(0,,,), User(1,,,), User(3,,,))
```

Another approach involves

```
teamMembers = List(teamMembers, usrList).flatten
```

Namely, we  create a list of lists and flatten them up onto a list.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're problem actually is, the usage is pretty straightforward:

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = List(4,5,6)
val c = a ::: b  // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
val d = a ++ b   // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Maybe the thing you're missing is that concatenation produces a *new* list that is the concatenation of the previous two?  Or that you can't reassign vals so you need to assign to a fresh variable name?